# Snowflake ODBC driver not using valid proxy environment variables?

Tags: proxy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a proxy at work that I'd like to use to connect PowerBI and Tableau to Snowflake. I should be able to set my proxies as the Snowflake documentation specifies, but this doesn't work for me when I try to connect to Snowflake using PowerBI or Tableau ('Couldn't resolve proxy name' errors).

I know that I am using a working proxy because I can use it manually to install Python libraries. Here is the Snowflake documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#using-environment-variables

As per the documentation, I am setting the proxy as follows via cmd line:

```
set http_proxy=<http_proxy>
set https_proxy=<https_proxy>
```

I've also tried setting these manually in env vars. I know that these proxies work because I can use them to install python libraries:

```
python -m pip --proxy <http_proxy> install -r <github_requirements>
```

What else might be stopping me from using the proxy? I went so far as to set-up a AWS EC2 to get around the proxy to ensure my credentials to snowflake were valid and they are. But I'd like to connect to Snowflake without AWS since that will eventually add an additional cost.

Comment: Are you able to get connected to Snowflake with hard-coded proxy values for Tableau and PowerBI?

Comment: Yes, I can with Tableau but only Tableau Desktop provides a 'Proxy=' capability. Tableau Online and PowerBI as a whole don't have a proxy config.